# constructor that creates another Subclass java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

If I have a class Car:

```
public class Car {

    int weight;
    Car(){}

    public Car(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

and another class Sedan that inherits from Car:

```
 public class Sedan extends Car { 

     public Sedan(int weight) {
         super(weight);
     }
 }
```

and a third class Jeep that also inherits from Car:

```
public class Jeep extends Car {

    public Jeep(int weight) {
        super(weight);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that when I say   `Car mercedes = new Car(5000);`

The constructor creates a `new Jeep` or a `new Sedan` depending on the given weight: `if( weight>3000)` , create a Jeep `mercedes=new Jeep(weight);` , else create a Sedan `mercedes=new Sedan(weight);` ?

Comment: Not within the constructor.  What you need is a Factory. (A method that calls the respective constructor)

Answer (score 8):

It seems you want to use [*factory pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). That means you create separate class, that's responsible to build and return respective `Car` object.

For example:

```
class CarFactory {
    public Car createCar(int weight) {
         if (weight < 3000) {
              return new Sedan(weight);
         } else {
              return new Jeep(weight);
         }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CarFactory carFactory = new CarFactory();
Car car = carFactory.createCar(yourDesiredWeight);
```

This not only helps you to solve problem but also helps you to organize your code in a better way. I.e. removes responsibility of creating car from class that will manipulate with class.

**Note:** I highly recommend you to read up on [*single responsibility principle (SRP, for short)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

**Note 2:** It seems class `Car` needs to be abstract since it's general base class for all derived types and does not make sense if initialized directly (`public abstract class Car {...}`).

Comment: I know about the factory pattern thing. I was wondering if it could be done directly in the constructor of Car. Thank You.

Comment: @user120404 You can't change type of instantiated object and if ctor is invoked it means that object has been instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this like you want.  What you're looking for is the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

```
    public abstract class AbstractCarFactory{
      public static Car createCar(int weight){
        Car ret=null;
          if (weight>3000) {
            car=new Jeep(weight);
          } else {
            car=new Sedan(weight);
          }
        return car;
      }
    }
```

**Add another option (that I don't recommend and is terrible form)**

You could merge the factory pattern a delegation pattern:

```
public class Car {
    private Car car;
    protected Car() {

    }
    public Car(int weight) {
        if (weight>3000) {
            car=new Jeep(weight);
        } else {
            car=new Sedan(weight);
        }
    }
    public String getType() {
        return car.getType();
    }
}
```

The Car class will construct a Jeep or Sedan, and delegate all calls to it.

```
public class Jeep extends Car {
    int weight;

    public Jeep(int weight) {
        super();
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return "JEEP";
    }
}
```

Again, this is really contrived and shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember encapsulation!

```
public class Car{

    private int weight ;

    public Car(){

    }

   public Car(int weight){
       this.weight = weight; 
   }

}
```

If you want to instantiate a car just :

```
   Car someCar = new Car(Insert Weight Here);
```

You can make that call anywhere you want. This isn't how inheritance is usually used though.  You may want to clarify a little more. Usually you do things like:

```
Car somecar = new Jeep(4000);
```

or

```
Car somecar = new Sedan (1000);
```

but they are all cars in the end of the day